# Subdomains and Auth with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

I am created a project which has multiple different sections all stored within a subdomain for example:

```
core.sample.com
map.sample.com
character.sample.com
```

I want the user to only be able to login at: sample.com and see a page to select which section they want to go to.

I have created the first subdomain

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'core.rpsbackpack.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CoreController@index')->name('core.index');
});
```

However I now need to disable the login process or redirect to the main domain. However i cant work out how to get this working.
I have the Auth route at the top of the folder but I dont know if this is correct.

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['domain' => 'core.rpsbackpack.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CoreController@index')->name('core.index');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

What is the best way to easily support lots of subdomains?

Comment: Do you have another installation of laravel in the subdomains?

Comment: No i have a wildcard domain pointing to one instance of laravel and then I am using my routes folder to split up the sub domains @Eitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the domain config in your config/session.php to something like this, so the session is shared between subdomains.

```
'domain' => '.sample.com',
```